# How do I run multiple vibration motors from an Arduino Mini with PWM?

Tags: motor, pwm, arduino-pro-mini

I'm building a project for my Physical Computing class that involves 4 vibration motors for varied haptic feedback based on serial input via analogRead. I have each coming out of their own pin and assigned to conditionals.

I'm wondering:

- how do i control the PWM of each individual motor?
- assuming I need an external power source for the motors, do I need to have a diode and transistor in between each motor and the ground?

Thanks in advance - I'm still learning but definitely looking forward to taking Part II next semester!

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Answer (score 3):

1. You can control motor PWM by using AnalogWrite() feature. Arduino Mini is equipped with 6 PWM pin, so you can use 1 PWM pin for each of you motor. Check [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite) about more information on AnalogWrite, and [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) about Arduino Mini
2. This is the circuit if you want to use external power source. Normally, I use 1k ohm resistor, I'm sure there are someone out there that knows the exact formula.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTOHa5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why specifically use a zener diode as a flyback? Can't a regular diode (granted it can handle the voltage) do the trick? Is there a specific advantage of using a zener diode over a normal diode?

Comment: Sure regular diode will also works, I didn't mention anything about specifically using zener diode

Comment: Hi - thanks for the help. I'm pretty solid on the physical routing now, at this point, its more the code I'm worried about. I'm guessing I can use an elseif statement? So for example if I have `irPin1 = analogread(irVal1)` to set the analogRead for the IR sensor I'm using, and then:

'    if (irVal1 < 400){
      digitalWrite(vibePin1 = HIGH);
         }
        else(){
          digitalWrite(vibePin1 = LOW);
           }'

Comment: From there, how would I distribute PWM values to each sensor? I'm assuming that I'd be creating a pwmVal variable to store something? AnalogWrite(pwmVal = 30) or something like that? Assuming it goes 0-255.

Comment: dhimaspw, while you don't mention diode or zener diode in the text, item D in the diagram is a zener, as denoted by bends in the cathode line.  You could edit and substitute a plain diode with a straight line for cathode.

Comment: @jwpat7 as you suggested, I've change the circuit. Hope this doesn't cause any misunderstanding.

Comment: @Nick if there are new question, in my opinion you should post another question or edit the original instead of asking in comment section.